# Heroku and Mule

Tags: java, heroku, mule

I have a mule application that I want to deploy to Heroku. Has any one deployed Mule 3 application to Heroku. Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a simple bootstrap main for your Mule application:

```
public class MuleBootstrap
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final MuleServer ms = new MuleServer("mule-config.xml");
        ms.start(true, true);
    }
}
```

and use Maven to build and package it.

Find inspiration in [this Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java) for actually deploying the packaged application.